# sencha touch build formpanel dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Am new at sencha touch and 
I want to create a formPanel after the user click on some listener, I found out how to listen to An item, but the problem is to create a page and fill it with data coming from JsonP request 
I tried

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
url: 'url',
callbackName: 'callback1',
success: function(result, request) {


 Ext.Viewport.add({     
    title : 'Category',
    iconCls : 'home',
    id:'category'+id,
    xtype : 'formpanel',  
    deferredRender:true,
    tabBarPosition : 'bottom',
    data:result.prop
}); }});
```

in the console there is no error and the form added but not within the formpanel that already exist

Answer (score -1):

you could try sample code below..

```
onButtonClick: function(button) {

Ext.data.JsonP.request({
url: 'url',
callbackName: 'callback1',
success: function(result, request) {


 button.up('some_id').add({     
    title : 'Category',
    iconCls : 'home',
    id:'category'+id,
    xtype : 'formpanel',  
    deferredRender:true,
    tabBarPosition : 'bottom',
    data:result.prop
 }); 
}});

}
```